# Doppler effect- will frequency continually decrease?

Tags: waves, doppler-effect

[image]

[image]

My problems:

1. I know that when a person is moving away, the perceived frequency will be lower than the frequency of the source. However, in the question, if the person is moving away, the perceived frequency WILL be lower by why would it continually decrease, would it just remain as $f'$
2. I also want to understand how the Doppler shift comes about... I know if the person is moving away, the successive wave fronts will be further apart. However, in the case of this question, will the person who is moving away instantly hear a difference in frequency as he starts moving or is there somewhat of a gradual transition from high to low frequency?

Answer (score 3):

The question, answers and explanation are poorly worded.

Since the observer's velocity changes, the nature of that change, his/her acceleration, is significant.

If the observer begins to accelerate away from the source, and continues to accelerate, then the perceived frequency will continue to decrease (as long as the observer stays sub-sonic!)  At any moment, the observed frequency reflect the Doppler shift for the velocity ***at that instant***.

If, on the other hand, the observer transitions ***instantly*** from being at rest to travelling away at some velocity $V$, then the frequency will similarly transition instantly to the frequency calculated by the Doppler shift for a velocity $V$.

Answer (score 2):

If the observer moves away with a constant velocity, they will hear a different frequency, but $f'$ will remain the same.  Perhaps the problem meant that the observer accelerated away, or it is possible that the textbook editors made a mistake (which happens more frequently than most people realize).

As for your second question - if the observer instantaneously goes from rest to, say, 5 m/s away from the source of the sound, then the sound change will be instantaneous.  This will not happen in practice, so during the acceleration from 0 m/s to 5 m/s, a somewhat gradual change in frequency will be heard.  The rate of change of the frequency will depend on the change in velocity and change in time.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the horn has a variable speed $v(t)$ relatively to the observer, the position  of the horn relatively to the observer is given by $x(t)=\int_0^t v(u) du$, supposing $x(0)=0$

Suppose we are interested only at the (periodic) maximums of the sound, corresponding to a period of the emitted sound, at $t_0$, $t_1=t_0 + T$, where $T$ is the sound period,  and where the period is the inverse of the frequency $T = \frac{1}{\nu}$.

The corresponding received signals for the observer, are at $t'_0 = t_0 + \frac{x(t_0)}{c}$, $t'_1= t_1 + \frac{x(t_1)}{c}$, where $c$ is the speed of sound.

Then the corresponding period for the observer, is $T' = t'_1-t'_0 = (t_1-t_0) + \frac{1}{c} (x(t_1)- x(t_0) = (t_1-t_0) + \frac{1}{c}\int_{t_0}^{t_1} v(u) du$ = $T + \frac{1}{c}\int_{t_0}^{t_0 + T} v(u) du$

Take the example of a constant accelerated movement, then $v(t) = at$,  so $x(t) = \frac{1}{2} a t^2$ (here $a>0$), so we have :

$T' = T + \frac{1}{c} a \frac{1}{2}(t_1^2- t_0^2) = T (1+ \frac{a}{2c} (t_0+t_1)) = T (1+ \frac{a}{2c} (2t_0 + T))$

We see that the period, seen by the observer, is continuously increasing with time (when $t_0$ is increasing).

The frequency being the inverse of the period, we see that the frequency seen by the observer, $\nu'$ , is continuously decreasing with time. We have :

$\nu' = \nu (\dfrac{\nu}{\nu + \frac{a}{2c}(1 + 2\nu t_0)}$)

You may prefer express $\nu'$ in function of $t'_0$ instead of $t_0$, with $t'_0= t_0 + \frac{a}{2c} t_0^2$. This will not change the conclusion because $t'_0$ is a monotone function of $t_0$